# Singular pronoun "it" working as a plural one

Tags: measure-expressions

Why in *time expressions* the singular pronoun "**it**" is able to replace "*they*"?:

> **It is** twenty to five in the  afternoon.

This rule also is used in quantity of people or things:

> - John: How many people could you see?
> - Anne: **There was** about twenty of them.

Why does this happen?

Comment: In your first example, "it" refers to "the time", a singular noun.

Comment: Your other two examples don't contain the word "it" so I'm not sure how they relate to the question in your title.

Comment: In any latin language this rule is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, "twenty minutes to five" is a time, and a time is always treated as singular. We don't say "five o'clock are ..."; we say "five o'clock is ...". "Twenty minutes to five is the time when we agreed to begin the meeting." Unless, I suppose, you are talking about a number of instances of that time. Like, "There are two three o'clocks every day."

When a number is an identifier of a thing, it is singular (assuming we are talking about an identifier of one thing). For example, we don't say, "My room are 214", but "My room is 214". Which is logical enough, as we are talking about one thing, even if it is identified by a number that is greater than 1.

Your second example is wrong. We don't say, "There was twenty people", we say, "There were twenty people." You could refer to the number as a thing in itself, in which case it would be singular. Like, "The number is twenty."

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences contain so-called expletive constructions ("it", "there"). These are "dummy words" which have no real meaning. Expletives occur when the syntax requires a subject, but there is no meaningful agent to do the action. They frequently occur with sentences involving weather, time and existential expressions:

> *It* is raining.
>   *It* is twenty to five.
>   *There* are lots of people.

For more on expletives, check out the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).